# mysql join when field are table name and primary key

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have to build a complex query on `SugarCRM`for a report. SugarCRM relationship it's stored on some tables, so I need to join multiple tables using the relationship tables. The tables have a `model` and `model_id` which identify a table and record primary id.

Below is an example of what I am trying to do.

- BLOGS : Main table with field ID
- BLOG_ENTRY : Child table of Blog with with field ID, BLOG_ID (FK of BLOGS table) and POST_CONTENT_ID (FK of next table BLOG_CONTENT)
- BLOG_CONTENT with field ID, MODEL (which identify a child table) and MODEL_ID (which identify child table id)
- BLOG_CONTENT_TABLE_ONE with field id

Suppose we can have more than one table BLOG_CONTENT_TABLE_TWO, ...

The query should be something like:

```
select blogs.id, blog_content.model, blog_content.model_id, blog_content_table_one.id 
from blogs, blog_entry, blog_content, blog_content_table_one
where 

# join blog and blog_entry
blog.id = blog_entry.blog_id 

# join blog_entry and blog_content
AND blog_entry.content_id = blog_content.id 

# join blog_content and blog_content_table_one
AND blog_content.model = 'blog_content_table_one'
AND blog_content.model_id =  blog_content_table_one.id
```

This works, but if there is more table, I suppose I should use a MySQL case ?

Comment: what about: "....AND blog_content.model IN (SELECT DISTINCT model FROM blog_content WHERE /*some condition*/"

Comment: Not sure how this can solve main problem: join correct records with correct child table... Can you post full query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use the `ON` clause for `JOIN`s. Second, I don't think it's possible to get all possible combinations, but for three blog content tables, you could go for something like this.

```
SELECT 
    blogs.id, 
    blog_content.model, 
    blog_content.model_id, 
    blog_content_table_one.id 
    blog_content_table_two.id 
    blog_content_table_three.id 
FROM blogs
JOIN blog_entry 
    ON blog.id = blog_entry.blog_id
JOIN blog_content 
    ON blog_entry.content_id = blog_content.id
LEFT JOIN $blogtable1 blog_content_table_one 
    ON blog_content.model_id =  blog_content_table_one.id
    AND blog_content.model = '$blogtable1'
LEFT JOIN $blogtable2 blog_content_table_two 
    ON blog_content.model_id =  blog_content_table_two.id
    AND blog_content.model = '$blogtable2'
LEFT JOIN $blogtable3 blog_content_table_three 
    ON blog_content.model_id =  blog_content_table_three.id
    AND blog_content.model = '$blogtable3'
WHERE blog_content.model IN ('$blogtable1', '$blogtable2', '$blogtable3')
```

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks! Why you don't think can't be added more possible combinations?

Comment: You can add more possibilities, but I think you can't create a query to have it in a dynamic way, e.g. without knowing how many tables there will be.

Comment: Ah... I understand. Of course. That is not an issue. Thanks!